# Getting filter to work using laravel and livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a filter using laravel and livewire. My filter will have 3 fields

1. a search box that looks for a product name
2. a drop down that gives me the status of the products
3. a drop down with options like 7 days ago and 30 days agothe date the products was made

The problem I'm having is that when my status drop down as All I'm not sure how to put that in my query also
how to I get my date to work with the created_at field.

Here is my code

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    use App\Models\Product;

    class Products extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;

        public string $search = '';
        public string $created_at = '';
        public string $status = '';

        public function render()
        {
            $products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                            ->where('status', $this->status)
                           ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', $created_at)
                            ->paginate(10);

            return view('products.livewire.products', ['products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    use App\Models\Product;

    class Products extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;

        public string $search = '';
        public string $created_at = '';
        public string $status = '';

        public function render()
        {
            //first we need to convert out created_at value from string to date to compare it with date value stored in database
            $c_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($created_at));

            $products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');

            //apply this filter only if the dropdown value ALL is not selected
            if($status != 'ALL'){
                $products->where('status', $this->status);
            }
            $products->where('status', $this->status)
            ->Where('created_at', '>=', $c_date)
            ->paginate(10);

            return view('products.livewire.products', ['products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get this error `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting identifier` but when I remove the othe `->` I get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links()`

Comment: @Aurilie just updated my answer. The second error you are getting is from your template file where you have called the $products->links() .

Comment: this is what I have {{ $products->links() }}

Comment: So I removed my `$products->links()` but my filter still isn't working. Now I'm not even getting the data when I select the correct values